# Sort array by Name in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've got an array as follows:

```
Array (
[id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3321
        [1] => 3318
        [2] => 3320
        [3] => 3319
        [4] => 3324
        [5] => 3322
    )

[name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Carla Taku
        [1] => Honey-Pearl Te Moni
        [2] => Monique Koroua
        [3] => Summer Hellier
        [4] => Wayne Kahukiwa
        [5] => Natasha Merito
    )

[courses] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 1
    )

)
```

I want to sort this by "name", but I can't work out how to do this. I can't make it multi-dimensional due to some other code. I've tried usort, ksort, array_sort, array_multisort, but I'm not experienced enough to sort this.

Comment: Do you mean sort all three based on sorting one column or sorting by last name?

Comment: @Anthony I want to sort all 3 if possible, based on the "name" column

Comment: Do you mean sort this on the basis of key like id,name,course .Please Give the details how you want to sort that will be helpful

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: @Anthony I've tried that, but wasn't sure what values to set it at? Any hints please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [`array_multisort`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) is what you are after:

```
array_multisort($array['name'], $array['id'], $array['courses']);
```

Comment: You my friend are a legend! Thanks! I just couldn't work out how it was supposed to be ordered. :)

Comment: Nice and simple instead of my multi-line below, you learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across sorting stuff yesterday. Hopefully this could give you some hint.

```
function SortByName($a,$b){
    return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

usort($YourArray, 'SortByName');
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I keep getting the error `Undefined index: name`? But if I echo the array after the function it's changed?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not using your specific array, I got lazy. However this should work for you, easy as pie.

```
$ar = array(
    array("10", 11, 100, 100, "a"),
    array(1, 2, "2", 3, 1)
);

$temp = $ar[1];

$count = 0;

asort($ar[0]);
foreach ($ar[0] as $key => $value) {
    $ar[1][$count] = $temp[$key];
    $count++;
}

print_r($ar);
```