# PHP Sort array by name

Tags: php, json, sorting

The data returning from my database is encrypted. so running a order by at the end of the SQL is not working. so I have to sort on the server side.

I see a lot a question about this I have tried a suggestions but I can't seem to get to
sort . I tried this [routine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176066/sort-array-by-name-in-php) (look like the closest to what I was looking for).

2 things are happening:

1: It don't sort by the name field(key)

2: Our in house app complains that its not a JSON string any longer.

I need to sort this my the name, so I need a custom sort

I get my array set like this:

```
$jsonData = array();

...connected to the DB.... stuff here...
//loop through the return:

if($result->num_rows > 0)
     {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
         {
               $row["name"] = $this->decryptData($row["name"]);
              $jsonData["groups"][] = $row ;

         }   

}


    $result->close();   
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    return $jsonData;
```

The return code looks like this:

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": "71",
      "name": "Bob",
       },
    {
      "id": "73",
      "name": "Howard",
    },
    {
      "id": "79",
      "name": "Sam",

    },....
  ....{
      "id": "65",
      "name": "Al",

    }
  ]
}
```

OK  so I added this code at the bottom of my routine to sort (notice I tried to methods):

.... code

```
        /*usort($jsonData, function($a, $b) {
           return $a['name'] - $b['name'];
        });*/

         usort($jsonData, function($a, $b) {
         return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
         });

    /* and I tried this get the same output but with a php error say what I have is not a array
        array_multisort($jsonData['name']);
          -- and this--
        array_multisort($jsonData['groups']['name']);

   */



$result->close();   
        mysqli_close($mysqli);
        return $jsonData;
```

and I get this result which is little different than what I need and its not sorted by name:

```
[
   [
        {
          "id": "71",
          "name": "Bob",
           },
        {
          "id": "73",
          "name": "Howard",
        },
        {
          "id": "79",
          "name": "Sam",

        },....
      ....{
          "id": "65",
          "name": "Al",

        }
      ]
]
```

I'm lost at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply arithmetics to string values for comparisons; you need a string function instead, such as [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/strcmp) or [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/strcasecmp) which return a value of -1, 0, or 1:

```
usort($jsonData, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

Comment: Hi Jack and thanks I missed that, however even with the change I 'm still not getting it sorted by name in ascending order

Comment: @Mike That just means that `$a` and `$b` are either not arrays or don't have the `'name'` key. Have you tried applying the sort to `$jsonData['groups']`?

Comment: Yes I did usort($jsonData["group"], function($a, $b) 
 {  return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
  }); but I get a error saying that the 1st pram is not a array. which now I'm thinking my var $jsonData is not correct

Comment: @Mike If it's an object you should use `$a->name` and `$b->name`.

Comment: not sure but that fixed it, thanks! I need to do some reading on object and arrays. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usort`

`usort($jsonData['group'], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['name'] - $b['name'];
});`

and try to `print_r($jsonData)`

Comment: Yes I did usort($jsonData["group"], function($a, $b) { return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']); }); but I get a error saying that the 1st pram is not a array. which now I'm thinking my var $jsonData is not correct –

Comment: @mike try `usort($jsonData['group'], function($a, $b) { return $a->name - $b->name; });`